# How to filter a objectlist in javascript by date

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, date, filters

I have lightning controller in were I want to filter a list based on a datefield. I tried the following but end up with an empty list:

My list has 2 records:

```
serverList[0].Startdatum__c = 1-12-2018
serverList[1].Startdatum__c = 30-7-2018

startdate = 02-08-2018


var serverListFilteredbyDate = serverList.filter(function(item) { return item[(serverList[i].Startdatum__c >= startDate)]});
```

Comment: Should not it be like - `var serverListFilteredbyDate = serverList.filter(function(item) {return item.Startdatum__c >= startDate;});` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, you're trying to subtract numbers (02-08-2018 = -2024). Instead, you need to make sure you're using Date objects:

```
startdate = new Date("02-08-2018")
```

I believe you'll also need to do this for the values in the field as well.

As N.B. commented while I was writing, you use "item" (the variable) to do the filtering. You could actually write it more like this:

```
startdate = new Date("02-08-2018")
var serverListFilteredbyDate = serverList.filter(item => new Date(item.Startdatum__c) >= startDate);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I end up with an "item is not defined"

Comment: I just wrote similar code and tested it just now, it works for me.

Comment: When I replace item with serverList it works. Thanks!